# Using canActivate or canChildActivate throws error?

Tags: angular, typescript

Using `canActivateChild` or `canActivate` in the child route throws error. This thing worked fine earlier, but there seems to be issue this time. It throws an error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(8,7): error TS2322: Type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | { path: string; component: typeof Log...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
  Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; pathMatch: string; } | { path: string; component: typeof Logi...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
    Type '{ path: string; component: typeof MainContentComponent; canActivateChild: typeof PlayVidAuthGuard...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
      Types of property 'canActivateChild' are incompatible.
        Type 'typeof PlayVidAuthGuardService' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
          Property 'includes' is missing in type 'typeof PlayVidAuthGuardService'.
```

Here is my routing module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "home",
    component: MainContentComponent,
    canActivateChild: PlayVidAuthGuardService,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: PlayVideoComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now the error goes away when I remove `canActivateChild` attribute/field.

```
export class PlayVidAuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor() {}
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Even when I put `canActivate` inside of the child route, I get the same error.
How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implement `CanActivate` interface but you assign to the `canActivateChild`. For `canActivateChild` you need to implement `CanActivateChild` interface.

And also this properties must be initialized with array.

```
...
canActivateChild: [ PlayVidAuthGuardService ]
...
```

This error

> Property 'includes' is missing in type 'typeof
>   PlayVidAuthGuardService'.

says that Angular tries to find a function with name `includes` on the `canActivateChild` which is not found because you have assigned ***not an array***.

Answer (score 0):

These guard fields expect an array, so wrap your guard inside an array with one element:

```
// Change this... 
// canActivate: YourGuard, 

//... to this:
//           v         v
canActivate: [YourGuard],
```